# IE8 has started ignoring return false;

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8

On our site we have a couple of forms that have onSubmit Jquery calls.  An example of one is:

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="$.cms.addToBasket('@product.ProductCode', '@product.ProductDescription', 1, @(product.CanPaint ? 1 : 0), @((this.Model.Context.WebSite.IsReseller || this.Model.Context.Session.Login.IsBodyShop || this.Model.Context.Session.HidePaintBox).ToTrueFalseString())); return false;">
```

The Jquery call works but then straight after the form action is called.  this happens in IE8 and below.  It works as planned in other browsers such as IE10, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The only reason it would "ignore" the `return false;` is if it were never reached, such as when there's an error in the script. Check the browser's error console.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you really should not have any code embedded in your HTML like this. Your code should be written in a jQuery event handler -- eg `$('#myForm').submit(function() { ..... });`.

Comment: Thanks Spudley, moving the code to an event handler did the trick.